# Multiple Swiper Sliders in Angular reduces performance to zero and triggers thousands times ngDoCheck

Tags: angular

I have multiple Swiper Slider Components on one page which is actually another parent component Users List(`<users-list>`), for example. Everything works fine if this parent component holds only 2-3 Swipers. But when it comes to 10-20 the things go wrong. Performances reduces to zero, scroll stops working, buttons become not clickable and so on.

I've noticed that each Swiper Slider Component triggers `ngDoCheck` in my parent component (`<users-list>`) even for every mousemove. I logged every trigger and I see in console thousands of triggers. And when I remove Swiper Slider Component from parent component everything goes well. There's no so many checks. I've changed `changeDetectionStrategy` in `UsersListComponent` and `SwiperComponent` as well to `onPush` but that ddidn't help - `ngDoCheck` keeps being triggered all the time.

What the problem it can be? I couldn't find the solution and I'm really curious about it....

*swiper-image.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'images-swiper',
  templateUrl: './images-swiper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./images-swiper.component.scss'],
})
export class ImagesSwiperComponent
  implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @Input() images: Array<Image>;

  private swiper: Swiper;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        speed: 400,
        spaceBetween: 100,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        initialSlide: 0,
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          type: 'bullets',
          clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Then I have a component `<user-tile>` which holds this Swiper component something like let's say user tile (each tile has User info and Swiper component)>. And then finally I have a list of users which holds numerous user tiles with Swiper Sliders.

Long story short it looks like this (schematically)

*user-list.component.html*

```
 <users-list>
       <user-tile *ngFor=let user of users [user]="user"><user-tile>
 </users-list>
```

*user-tile.component.html*

```
<user-tile>
    {{ user.info }}
   <images-swiper [images]="user.images"></images-swiper>
<user-tile>
```

Comment: Please provide context. Are you working in Angular for web? Or hybrid aka Ionic?

Comment: it is Angular for web

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you are using the pure Web Swiper API (https://swiperjs.com/get-started/) inside Angular. In any situation it is a bad idea, to use any library that is not 'Angular aware' inside Angular, as while trying to modify the DOM, both Angular and Swiper will conflict (causing many checks and DOM updates).

Try always to use a wrapper designed for Angular (or build your own). In your case: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper

Comment: I have a particular Angular component for Swiper. I can't consider it as a such wrapper? :))) sorry if this question is very stupid haha

Comment: No, a proper wrapper, is a component that has been implemented in such a way, that the library rather than conflicting with Angular is cooperating. Sometimes is as simple as few lines of code, other times requires quite extensive work to integrate something, see for yourself: https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper/tree/master/projects/app/src

Comment: ah I got it. Thanks a lot for the explanation! I will try the Andular wrapper you mentioned before

Answer (score 0):

Swiper now support **Angular**

Three simple steps:

1- Uninstall the current used **Swiper** library.

2- Install this: https://swiperjs.com/angular

3- Remove any configs (this is very important)

```
  this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { ....
```

and use directive instead